# Load a json object from postgres into ember-data via rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to create an Ember.js app where in the model, I load in a JSON as an object. (Just to display for now.)

Here is my rails schema:

```
  create_table "recipes", force: true do |t|
    t.integer "recipe_id"
    t.integer "version"
    t.string  "author"
    t.json    "recipe"
    t.json    "steps"
    t.integer "parent_id"
 end
```

And the serializer in ember:

```
class ProtocolSerializer < ActiveModel::Lead
    attributes :recipe_id, :version, :author, :recipe, :steps, :parent_id
end
```

What is the proper way to make the model? This is the best that I got, but I am not sure how to import the json properly. A string would be fine if that is easier:

```
App.Protocol = DS.Model.extend
  recipe_id: DS.attr('int')
  version: DS.attr('int')
  author: DS.attr('string')
  recipe: DS.attr('string')
  steps: DS.attr('string')
  parent_id: DS.attr('int')
```

Thanks so much!

EDIT: I think I figured it out- importing json as a string works just fine except it removes the '{ }' from the final web page. Instead of 'int' I should have used 'number'.